# Is entalphy a presence of energy or a change in energy?

Tags: definition, thermodynamics

I see that the words [enthalpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy) and change in enthalpy are often used  interchangibly.
Do they mean the same thing?

Are *change in enthalpy* and *enthalpy* different?

What is the true definition of enthalpy?

Comment: When you say `change in enthalpy` do you then mean `change in energy`? (That is what your title says, but not the question)

Comment: Can you provide some reference for "I see that the words are use interchangibly"?

Comment: no I often see these words used interchangeably in my class 11 ncert text book ...that's d reason I get confused most f d times

Comment: well steeven I meant to say that is enthalpy a presence of energy?in the sence does the word enthalpy refer to a presence of energy or a change in energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy):

> The total enthalpy, H, of a system cannot be measured directly. The same situation exists in classical mechanics: only a change or difference in energy carries physical meaning. Enthalpy itself is a thermodynamic potential, so in order to measure the enthalpy of a system, we must refer to a defined reference point; therefore what we measure is the change in enthalpy, ΔH. The change ΔH is positive in endothermic reactions, and negative in heat-releasing exothermic processes.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: well seems lyk ur answer helped me in understanding the concept well...bt  what did you mean by saying a "defined reference point".

Comment: it means that the enthalpy, like the energy, is always defined up to a constant. It is not meaningful to talk of the enthalpy as an absolute number $H$ (like the temperature in Kelvin). It only makes sense to talk of differences $\Delta H \equiv H - H_0$ where $H_0$ is a *defined reference point*, i.e. some number arbitrarily choosen as reference. It can be taken as 0 or something else, it doesn't matter (of course, the choice must be consistent throughout a reasoning, though).

Comment: @BhargavaSisir  Kurella :Please write ' ''like'' not ''lyk'' and ''your'' not ''ur'' even in comments and specially in Ans and questions.